# Jinja2 template include another template from parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I have a jinja2 template at one location and want to include another common template from parent directory. What would be the best approach?

```
templates
   |
   - common.jinja2
   |
   - school
       | 
       - address.jinja2
```

So, in `address.jinja2`   I would like to include `common.jinja2`

Any pointers on how this can be achieved from the template file itself? Should I use the relative approach?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of doing anything special. `common.jinja2` can be included in `address.jinja2` just by using `{% extends "common.jinja2" %}` or `{% include "common.jinja2" %}` depending on your use case. This is because the paths are considered relative to root `templates` directory.